# Reinstall macOS on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I recently installed win10 via Bootcamp on my MacBook Pro 2016 but I wasn’t able to restart into macOS. Holding the option key upon boot wouldn’t do anything and the laptop would still boot into Windows.
So I reinstalled win10 from a flash drive by clicking on setup.exe in the win10 install folder. It gave me all sorts of trouble, but I was finally able to boot back into Windows again.
However, at this point, the keyboard and trackpad don’t work at all. I tried booting into the BIOS or booting from an external flash drive to install the latest version of win10 (2004) but nothing works.
I created a Bootcamp drivers flash drive to install Bootcamp manually but it says something like “Bootcamp is not compatible with this PC”. That was with the latest Bootcamp version. I also tried with Bootcamp 5.1, same thing; I can’t install any driver.
While reinstalling Windows I was at one point able to see the macOS partition, so my guess is, it’s still there.
I just want to get back to macOS.
I tried the key combinations of Mac to access boot manager, recovery, reset PRAM, SMC, but nothing works, as it seems my keyboard is not functional also during boot.
Is there a way I can reinstall macOS? I don’t have any important data on the laptop. So any way to wipe everything and reinstall macOS would help.
I also tried internet recovery, then again it didn’t work.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If holding down the option key at startup led to the booting of Windows instead of the Mac Startup Manager, the you probably did not do it right. Or, as you have suggested, the keyboard is not functional. You stated internet recovery did not work. That is a little vague. Could you add more details?

Comment: So, I was able to get windows to install somehow, with a different installer and it gave me all sorts of trouble.
I also got macOS back somehow.
I initiated a windows install by going to the recovery option and selecting command prompt. From there I opened setup.exe on the flash drive and went through the steps. I then formatted all partitions but the one that still had macOS and the laptop booted back to its original OS.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I meant by that, the laptop wouldn't boot into Internet recovery. My guess is the boot manager was deactivated, that's why initially holding the option key at boot wouldn't do anything.

Comment: A more specific answer to your original problem would be this: If you are using APFS and have correctly installed Windows 10 and the Windows Support Software from Apple, then you may will not be able to boot back to macOS from Windows. This problem can be corrected by running Apple Software Update from Windows until all the updates are downloaded and installed.

Comment: I see. I will try running Apple Software Update next time. Thanks